# How to remove element from array when button tapped

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have an add button that adds the current Item object to a finalList array. I am attempting to implement the remove button to remove that current item from the same array if it has already been added. The items are on a full page UICollectionViewCell along with the add and remove buttons.

```
   var finalList = [Item]()
    private var hiddenRows = Set<Int>()
@objc func addTapped(cell: PostCell) {

      guard let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPath(for: cell)  else {return}
      hiddenRows.insert(indexPath.row)
      cell.removeButton.isHidden = false

      let item = itemsArr[indexPath.row]

  //  cell.currentPrice += Float(item.price) ?? 0

    finalList.append(item)
    collectionView?.reloadData()
      totalPrice += Float(item.price) ?? 0
    cell.finalLabel.text = String(cell.currentPrice)

       }


@objc func removeButtonTapped(cell: PostCell) {
    guard let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPath(for: cell)  else {return}
    hiddenRows.insert(indexPath.row)
    cell.myButton.isHidden = false
    let item = itemsArr[indexPath.row]

  //  finalList.remove(at: item.)
    totalPrice -= Float(item.price) ?? 0
    cell.currentPrice -= Float(item.price) ?? 0
    cell.finalLabel.text = String(cell.currentPrice)
 //   collectionView?.reloadData()
     }

  extension CollectionViewController {

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return itemsArr.count
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! PostCell

            cell.delegate = self

      let item = itemsArr[indexPath.row]
    let page = itemsArr[indexPath.item]
    cell.set(name: item.name, brand: item.brand, price: item.price)

    print(finalList)
     if hiddenRows.contains(indexPath.row) {

                cell.myButton.isHidden = true
                cell.removeButton.isHidden = false
            }else{
                cell.removeButton.isHidden = true
                cell.myButton.isHidden = false
            }



    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a uique key suppose it's name

```
finalList.removeAll { $0.name == item.name }
```

In remove don't use `insert` instead also use

```
hiddenRows.removeAll { $0 == indexPath.row }
```

Comment: thank you, removeAll is a better path to use than insert?

Comment: I get an error Cannot convert value of type '(Int) -> Bool' to expected argument type 'Bool' on hiddenRows.